# Finding Web Part IDs

Tags: list, web-part

How do I find an Announcement Web Part ID in the existing html code?  I want to change the color of the alternating items in a specific list - view.

Answer (score 2):

Open up your page in Chrome. Right click somewhere on your Announcements web part and select inspect element. And then navigate through the resulting console until you get the ID of web part. I'm pretty sure it will be id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2" or similar.

Comment: I may need to be able to get this WebPartId via JavaScript.